# Can you push multiple artifacts into one scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When you call `sfdx force:force:push` there is no param to specify which artifact you'd like to push.

In the `./sfdx-project.json` file you have package directories and you can specify a default:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "my-main-artifact",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "my-less-important-artifact",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "42.0"
}
```

So presumably it's picking `my-main-artifact` as the one to push?

If I have multiple artifacts in this repo though how do I easily switch between the one I want to push? It's like there is an "active" artifact - is this just controlled from that default flag?

Comment: Just bumping an old thread here to see if there is an update on this discovery?

Answer (score 4):

#### The short answer is no, you can't control which artifact to push with sfdx-project.json

> The CLI uses the default package directory as the target directory when pulling changes in the scratch org to sync the local project. This default path is also used when creating second-generation packages.

[Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm)

That means all what specified in sfdx-project.json will be affected by `force:status/push/pull`.
This setting only allow CLI to identify where to put **newly created components** on scratch org when doing `force:pull`, that do not belong to any artifact yet.

#### Let me share my expirience here

That is ok to use this approach if artifacts do not depend on each other, but in my case they do.

As a workaround or tmp solution, until we could specify additional params in force:push , which I hope would be available in the future, I use forceignore for that.

Here is piece of my sfdx-project.json.

`{"path": "force-app/base", "default": true},
{"path": "force-app/ext_aff", "default": false},
{"path": "force-app/ext_amz", "default": false}`

`ext_aff & ext_amz` can not be pushed together with `base`, because they have dependencies on sobjects.
So, `base` and only it should go first and only then `ext_aff & ext_amz` could be pushed successfully.

Here is my flow for that:

1. Create scratch
2. Run `force:status` to have `sourcePathInfos` populated
3. Update `.forceignore` and add `force-app/ext_aff and force-app/ext_amz`
4. Run `force:push`, doing #3 pushes only `base` and ignores dependent extensions
5. Update `.forceignore` and remove `force-app/ext_aff and force-app/ext_amz`
6. Run `force:push` again and now extensions are pushed

After all of this I would be able to work scratch, update any exisitng metadata and successfully pull it.
In case I need to create something new, I'll switch `default` flag to `true` on artifact where I want to put newly created component.